# Capitalize the first letter of a given range

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to put a capital letter on the first word on a whole column, data (v7:v).

I found a script but it does not work:

```
function proper() {
  var arr = [],
    s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    s.getRange('b2:b').getValues().forEach(function (r) {
      if (r[0]) arr.push([toTitleCase(r[0])])
    });
  s.getRange(2, 2, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
  }

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0)
        .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
        .toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

moreover I wish that this script works only on a given sheet.

I tested with:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var s=ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
```

Comment: I posted a solution here and it works with no glitches: [Capitalize Each Word in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469449/apps-script-how-to-format-a-cell-to-proper-text-case/76350001#76350001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me but I'm guessing that you actually wanted the script to actually change the same column.  That script was simply showing you how to do it by copying the words capitalized into another column.

That's probably not what you wanted so I took that code and set it up to capitalize all of the words in column A.  Don't forget to change the name of the sheet to what you want.

```
function proper() {
    var arr = [];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var s=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
    s.getRange('a:a').getValues().forEach(function (r) {
      if (r[0]) arr.push([toTitleCase(r[0])])
    });
  s.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  }

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0)
        .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
        .toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

Comment: it's great, but sometimes I have this error:

"The spreadsheets service expired"

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one.  Do you have GSuite or some kind of paid account?