# Apps script how to format a cell to Proper Text (Case)

Tags: google-apps-script, capitalize

I have a form coming to my sheet, and sometimes my customers enter the text in lower or upper case, and aso with line breaks

I have this code to make a cell UPPERCASE and remove the line breaks

```
var val = responses.getRange( i + 1 , 13).getValue();
    val = val.replace(/\n/g,", ");
    responses.getRange( i + 1 , 13).setValue(val.toUpperCase());
```

What I need is to make that cell to Proper Case, not UpperCase

For example if the text is "hello how ARE YOU" I want to convert to "Hello How Are You" or also to "Hello how are you"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to modify from `hello how ARE YOU` to `Hello How Are You` and `Hello how are you` using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

The flow of this modification is as follows.

At first, the value is modified to lowercase.

- At pattern 1, the first characters of each word modify to uppercase.
- At pattern 2, the first character of value modifies uppercase.

#### Sample script:

```js
var val = "hello how ARE YOU";

var pattern1 = val.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/ig, function(match) {return match.toUpperCase()});
var pattern2 = val.toLowerCase().replace(/^[a-z]/i, function(match) {return match.toUpperCase()});

console.log(pattern1) // Hello How Are You
console.log(pattern2) // Hello how are you
```

#### Reference:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

If you need other patterns, can you provide them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in order to use the PROPER function in apps script for anyone else.

First I put the function in the cell using the name (in this case customer). Then I used the getDisplayValue to get the actual text. Then wrote it back out to the cell.

```
    customer = sht.getRange(row, col).setValue('=PROPER("'+customer+'")').getDisplayValue(); 
    sht.getRange(row, col).setValue(customer);
```

A bit of a hack/alternative but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead.  It will capitalize each word inside the cell.  You can set a trigger to "on edit" or to run once a day or every hour, etc.

With this code, you can easily change the range, so instead of C3:D (start at row 3 and include columns C AND D) you can use C:D (all rows in columns C and D), or C:C, or C3:C, etc.  You get the idea. I tested the code and I'm currently using it.  No glitches.

```
function textCase1Name() {

  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3:D")

  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  .map(row => row.map(col => (col) ? col.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/ig, function(match) {return match.toUpperCase()}) : col))

  range.setValues(values);
}
```